# How to draw calls from constructors in UML sequence diagrams?

Tags: constructor, uml, sequence-diagram

I've seen multiple ways to draw constructors, namely like [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSHUF_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.testrt.studio.doc/topics/crtumlovw.htm) with tails under them (function call) but more often like [here](http://www.vainolo.com/2012/05/02/factory-method-design-pattern-uml-modeling/) without the tails and with no arrow returning (sometimes with the label `<<create>>`).

I'm aware that there are differences between UML1 and UML2 and I'm not sure if this is one of them, however either way I cannot find any references as to how I can represent method calls from the constructor of an object.

EDIT: Example java code below. Say oour entry point is `foo()`. The main thing that I'm curious about is how to draw the `B()` constructor.

```
class A {
    private B b;
    public foo() {
        b = new B(this);
    }
}

class B {
    public B(A a) {
        foo();
        a.bar();
    }
}
```

Comment: As for the "_any references_" part see http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html and in there search for "create message" and see also https://www.websequencediagrams.com/examples.html. In order to answer the "_calls from constructors_" part show us some code that you want to draw in UML. BTW: some UML modeling tools (not just a picture drawing tools) can do the appearance decisions automatically for you

Comment: Example code added. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [websequencediagrams script](http://www.websequencediagrams.com/?lz=VXNlci0-YTpBOiBmb28KQS0tPj4rQjogPDxjcmVhdGU-PgpCLT5CABgGQi0-QTogYmFyCkItLT4-QToAKgZVc2VyOgo&s=rose) seems to capture your code

```
User->A: foo
A-->>+B: <<create>>
B->B: foo
B->A: bar
B-->>A:
A-->>User:
```

[image]

You can validate the notation against http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams-reference.html

**EDIT:** And this is the same message sequence as drawn by [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html)

[image]

Comment: Interesting. For some reason I thought the dashed line has to point to the box of the object... Does look valid though. Thanks!

Comment: @GaborMagyar that's right. See my edited answer for an example of how is this message sequence drawn by Enterprise Architect (after raw input). [uml-diagrams.org](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#create) comments this as "_..Note, that this weird convention to send a message to a nonexisting object to create itself is used both in UML 1.x and 2.x. In OOAD practice create message should probably be sent to the class, see [Message in OOAD](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-object-oriented-concepts.html#message) discussion for the backgound information.._"

Comment: what about constructor with parameters?

Comment: @artificerpi If your work doesn't need to be strictly standard-compliant (pieces of documentation rarely need to), I'd say both `<<create>>(param)`, and `<<create>>` followed by `<init>(param)` is understandable enough. Personally I'd say `<<create>>(param)` is more readable. As of hard standards, seconding.

Answer (score 3):

UML specs (2.5 beta) says about that

> An object creation Message (messageSort equals createMessage) has a dashed line with an open arrow head.

Figure 17.14 illustrates this:
[image: UML 2.5 Figure 17.14]
But anyway you do it I would model [each operation in its own sequence diagram](http://bellekens.com/2011/05/27/uml-best-practice-one-operation-one-sequence-diagram/).
So I would model your code example above as such:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not show what the body of a constructor must look like.

Comment: @GaborMagyar I added an example based on your code to illustrate